# gitで作業ディレクトリを最新のコミットした状態に戻す

Tags: git

作業ディレクトリでコードを書いてdb:migrateなどをしたあと、 
不備が見つかったのでそのコードを破棄して、 
githubにcommitした状況に作業ディレクトリを戻したいんですが、 
なかなかうまくいかず困っています。

どれが効果的かわからなかったので、 
以下の３つを試したりしたのですが、まだうまくいっていないです。 
git reset --hard 
git checkout master 
git pull origin master

誰かどうすれば教えていただけたら、ありがたいです！

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/49803

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git の動作が何もわからなくてもできるのは、新しく github から clone しなおすことだったりします。

これができない制約などありますか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！確かにおっしゃる通りgit clone git@github.com:username/project.gitでうまくいきました。昨日やった時のログを見てみると間違って、projectの中に入ったままでgit cloneをしていたので、それでうまくいかなかったようです。。

Comment: もしこの回答で問題が解決したならば、左にあるチェックをクリックして、承認してもらえると嬉しいです。

Comment: チェックしました！また何かありましたら、その時も宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

```
git checkout -- ./
```

でカレントディレクトリ以下が最後の commit 時に戻ります。
最後の commit が GitHub に push された物である保証はありませんので、そこは確認して下さい。
`./`はカレントディレクトリを指しますが、特定のファイルを指定する事も出来ます。

変更内容が失われてしまう事に注意して下さい。
一時的に変更内容を隠しておく`git stash`という操作もあります。

Comment: 私は`db:migrate`が何を意味するか解っていません。念の為。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！次に同じような状況に遭遇したときに'git checkout -- ./'を使ってみます。今回は色々試していたら、'rake db:migrate'で追加したマイグレーションファイルを'git clean -df'で偶然にもうまく消せました。